# NSDateFormatter's init method is deprecated?

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsdateformatter

Per

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

The `init` method of `NSDateFormatter` is "Available in iPhone OS 2.0 through iPhone OS 3.2", and therefore *not* in 4.0.  Now, it certainly works, but this seems odd.  Is this is a mistake or is there some other way to create a `NSDateFormatter`?

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: Official documentantion: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

Comment: I am pretty sure "setLocale" and "setTimeStyle" are the right ways to do this, I am just curious how you are supposed to get the NSDateFormatter instance now?

Comment: +1, this is hilarious. I wonder what Apple is thinking? I have to think it's somehow a mistake. I hope someone figures this out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This deprecation is just apple cleaning up the headers for NSDateFormatter. init is already declared in NSObject which NSNumberFormatter inherits from. Redeclaring is not necessary, however in the implementation apple will override init as subclassess should provide implementations for the default initializer of the superclass.

Comment: Thank you very much for that explanation. VERY misleading on Apple's part. It should not be marked as deprecated.

Comment: However, it is still useful to have *documentation* for the init method for this class, to describe what the implementation in this class does. e.g. "initializes formatter with default format", etc.

Answer (score 6):

Like `falconcreek` said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182314/nsdateformatters-init-method-is-deprecated), Apple is just clearing the docs.

That means that originally, `- (id) init` has been redeclared in the NSDateFormatter header file. That was unnecessary and somebody just removed it later. The documentation is probably generated automatically and didn't picked up that it was only the redecleration that was deprecated.

In short, use `init` as you wish with `NSDateFormatter`!

Comment: I think the documwentation is highly misleading.  I've used the "no not helpful" link to send a comment to Apple.

Answer (score 2):

I would trust the header files over the documentation.

For example, [Formatter Behaviors and OS Versions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-DontLinkElementID_1) seems to contradict itself:

> By default, on Mac OS X v10.4 instances of `NSDateFormatter` have the same behavior as they did on Mac OS X versions 10.0 to 10.3. On Mac OS X v10.5 and later, `NSDateFormatter` defaults to the 10.4+ behavior.
>
> If you initialize a formatter using `initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:`, you are (for backwards compatibility reasons) creating an “old-style” date formatter. To use the new behavior, you initialize the formatter with `init`. If necessary, you can set the default class behavior using `setDefaultFormatterBehavior:`), you can set the behavior for an instance using `setFormatterBehavior:` message with the argument `NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4`.

It sounds like `initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:` is actually the deprecated method?

Comment: Exactly right, it does seem that `initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:` is actually the deprecated method. The header files are what one should refer to in circumstances like this.

Answer (score 1):

That’s really strange. Maybe `+[NSDateFormatter new]` will do the job?

Comment: If `init` is deprecated, then `+new` is, too, because `+new` is nothing but `+alloc/-init` anyway (but good guess).

Answer (score 0):

I use the init method in an multiple iOS4 apps and they are approved and in the store. I can think of no way to get it to work so it would seem like its just a typo on the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The example code in the class reference still uses the `init` method, so I'd say its safe to use it in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can proof yourself that `NSDateFormatter` has a different behaviour dependent on the initializer you choose and the SDK you are compiling with. The following is tested with SDK 10.5 and 10.6.

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd" allowNaturalLanguage:NO];
if ([df formatterBehavior] == NSDateFormatterBehavior10_0)
    NSLog(@"NSDateFormatterBehavior10_0");
else if ([df formatterBehavior] == NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4)
    NSLog(@"NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4");
```

This returns `NSDateFormatterBehavior10_0`.
Instead, when you use `[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];` the behaviour is `NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4`.