# -[NSDateFormatter init] unsupported?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSDateFormatter's init method is deprecated?!?!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182314/nsdateformatters-init-method-is-deprecated)

I have just read in the docs that `-[NSDateFormatter init]` has been superseded and may become unsupported in the future. My question is without using init whats the prefered way to do the following in iOS4?

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
NSString *currentTime = [formatter stringFromDate:[newLocation timestamp]];
[formatter release];
```