# Overhead of the NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:dateStyle:timeStyle: class method

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

`NSDateFormatter` includes the following convenience method:

`+ (NSString *)localizedStringFromDate:(NSDate *)date dateStyle:(NSDateFormatterStyle)dateStyle timeStyle:(NSDateFormatterStyle)timeStyle`

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) states that using this method is the same as explicitly doing this:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[formatter setDateStyle:dateStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:timeStyle];
NSString *result = [formatter stringForObjectValue:date];
```

Now, I have read in various places that initialising an `NSDateFormatter` object has quite an overhead.  Does anyone know if the `localizedStringFromDate:etc` class method has the same overhead i.e. it causes the instantiation of a new `NSDateFormatter` object under the covers every time it is called?

Answer (score 1):

I am using my `NSDateFormatter`s as static variables which I initialize lazily. Like this the init routine is only called once:

```
static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
if (!formatter) {
   formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [formatter setDateStyle:dateStyle];
   [formatter setTimeStyle:timeStyle];
}
NSString *result = [formatter stringFromDate:date]; 
// reuse
[formatter setDateStyle:anotherDateStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:anotherTimeStyle];
NSString *anotherResult = [formatter stringFromDate:anotherDate];
```

Comment: Thanks - this is the kind of thing I normally do (or use a singleton).  I was just curious about what was happening under the covers when the class method is called.  I will try to work it out myself.

Comment: This is not thread-safe. [See How to minimize the costs for allocating and initializing an NSDateFormatter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442074/how-to-minimize-the-costs-for-allocating-and-initializing-an-nsdateformatter) for discussion

Comment: The referenced question is really quite a different scenario, involving stress testing the creation of many date formatters. In this case, there is only one.