# Is caching a NSDateformatter application-wide good idea?

Tags: ios, cocoa, caching, swift, nsdatepicker

It's [well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832768/why-is-allocating-or-initializing-nsdateformatter-considered-expensive) known that creating NSDateFormatters is '[expensive](http://www.rsaunders.co.uk/2012/02/nsdateformatter-are-expensive.html)'

Even Apple's [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW10) (updated 2014-02) states:

> Creating a date formatter is not a cheap operation. If you are likely to use a formatter frequently, it is typically more efficient to cache a single instance than to create and dispose of multiple instances. One approach is to use a static variable.

But that doc seems not really up to date with swift and I also can't find anything about that in the latest [NSDateFormatter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSDateFormatterStyle) about caching the formatter so I can only assume that it's just as expensive for swift as it is for objective-c.

A lot of sources suggest [caching](https://coderwall.com/p/yjnkwg/cache-nsdateformatter) the formatter inside the class using it, for example a controller or a view.

I was wondering if it would be handy or even 'cheaper' to add a singleton class to the project to store the datepicker so you're assured it's never necessary to create it again. This could be used everywhere in the app. You could also create several shared instances containing multiple datepickers. For example one datepicker for displaying dates and one for a time notation:

```
class DateformatterManager {
    var formatter = NSDateFormatter()

    class var dateFormatManager : DateformatterManager {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : DateformatterManager = DateformatterManager()
        }
        // date shown as date in some tableviews
        Static.instance.formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return Static.instance
    }

    class var timeFormatManager : DateformatterManager {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : DateformatterManager = DateformatterManager()
        }
        // date shown as time in some tableviews
        Static.instance.formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return Static.instance
    }

    // MARK: - Helpers
    func stringFromDate(date: NSDate) -> String {
        return self.formatter.stringFromDate(date)
    }
    func dateFromString(date: String) -> NSDate? {
        return self.formatter.dateFromString(date)!
    }
}

// Usage would be something like: 
DateformatterManager.dateFormatManager.dateFromString("2014-12-05")
```

Another likewise approach would be creating just one singleton and switching the format depending on the need:

```
class DateformatterManager {
    var formatter = NSDateFormatter()

    var dateFormatter : NSDateFormatter{
        get {
            // date shown as date in some tableviews
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            return formatter
        }
    }

    var timeFormatter : NSDateFormatter{
        get {
            // date shown as time in some tableviews
            formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
            return formatter
        }
    }

    class var sharedManager : DateformatterManager {
        struct Static {
            static let instance : DateformatterManager = DateformatterManager()
        }
        return Static.instance
    }

    // MARK: - Helpers
    func dateStringFromDate(date: NSDate) -> String {
        return self.dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    }
    func dateFromDateString(date: String) -> NSDate? {
        return self.dateFormatter.dateFromString(date)!
    }
    func timeStringFromDate(date: NSDate) -> String {
        return self.timeFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    }
    func dateFromTimeString(date: String) -> NSDate? {
        return self.timeFormatter.dateFromString(date)!
    }
}

// Usage would be something like: 
var DateformatterManager.sharedManager.dateFromDateString("2014-12-05")
```

Would either of those be a good or a horrible idea? And is switching the format also expensive?

**Update:**
As [Hot Licks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321993/is-caching-a-nsdateformatter-application-wide-good-idea#comment43104932_27321993) and [Lorenzo Rossi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321993/is-caching-a-nsdateformatter-application-wide-good-idea#comment57166060_27321993) point out, switching the formats is probably not such a good idea (Not thread safe and just as expensive as re-creating..).

Comment: Note that, regardless of whether NSDateFormatter itself is "thread safe", one must not change the format in one thread while there's a possibility that the formatter is being used in another thread.  This is one reason why it's best to have a global formatter have a fixed format, vs changing it with each use.

Comment: Nice one, thanks! That would not be a problem in the first example right? Where the format is not changed for each instance if I got it right.

Comment: I think for each type of format, you can have one date formatter.

Comment: Another good reason not to change the format is that it would provide **no** performance improvement: as it is stated in [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012-235/) **"Setting format is as expensive as recreating"**

Comment: Ah, did not know that. Thanks!

Comment: @LorenzoRossi good notice. Thanks for the WWDC video link!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I'll chime in here with an answer based on experience. The answer is yes, caching NSDateFormatter app-wide is a good idea, however, for added safety there is a step you want to take for this.

Why is it good? Performance. It turns out that creating NSDateFormatters is actually slow. I worked on an app that was highly localized and used a lot of NSDateFormatters as well as NSNumberFormatters. There were times that we dynamically created them greedily within methods as well as having classes that had their own copy of the formatters they needed. In addition, we had the added burden that there were cases where we could also display strings localized for different locales on the same screen. We were noticing that our app was running slow in certain cases, and after running Instruments, we realized it was formatter creation. For example we saw performance hit when scrolling table views with a large number of cells. So we ended up caching them by creating a singleton object which vended the appropriate formatter.

A call would look something like:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[FormatterVender sharedInstance] shortDate];
```

Note, this is Obj-C, but the equivalent can be made in Swift. It just happened ours was in Obj-C.

As of iOS 7, NSDateFormatters and NSNumberFormatters are "thread safe", however as Hot Licks mentioned, you probably don't want to go around modifying the format if another thread is utilizing it. Another +1 for caching them.

And another benefit I just thought of was code maintainability. Especially if you have a large team like we have. Because all devs know there is a centralized object that vends the formatters, they can simply see if the formatter they need already exists. If it doesn't, it gets added. This is typically feature related, and hence usually means that new formatter will be needed elsewhere as well. This also helps reduce bugs, because if there happens to be a bug in the formatter, you fix it one spot. But we usually catch that during the unit tests for the new formatter.

There is one more element you can add for safety, if you want. Which is you can use the NSThread's threadDictionary to store the formatter. In other words, when you call the singleton which will vend the formatter, that class checks the current thread's threadDictionary to see if that formatter exists or not. If it exists, then it simply returns it. If not, it creates it and then returns it. This adds a level of safety so if, for some reason you wanted to modify your formatter, you can do it and not have to worry about that the formatter is being modified by another thread.

What we used at the end of the day was singleton which vended specific formatters (both NSDateFormatter and NSNumberFormatter), ensuring that each thread itself had it's own copy of that specific formatter (note the app was created prior to iOS 7, which made that an essential thing to do). Doing that improved our app performance as well as got rid of some nasty side effects we experienced due to thread safety and formatters. Since we have the threadDictionary part in place, I never tested it to see if we had any issues on iOS7+ without it (ie. they have truly become thread-safe). Thus why I added the "if you want" above.

Comment: First of all, great answer! I added an answer below, illustrating your points. Just out of interest, is this the way you did it ? Naively enough, I have had issues in the past neglecting the fact that cross-thread access would cause problems (it certainly did, otherwise I wouldn't be here). Despite the fact that I'm running >iOS7, your solution seemed to have alleviated any problems I had in the past. Do you have any idea why that is (despite the fact that NSDateFormatter is supposed to be thread-safe) ? If it were I wouldn't be having any problems with just a shared instance, right ?

Comment: Actually the way I did it was differently. I created a formatter factory which vended specific formatters that I needed. For example, I needed different style date formatters (eg. a short variant and a longer version). Each formatter was given an explicit name and was referenced that way. For example: DATE_FORMATTER_SHORT.

Comment: Regarding your issues, what types of problems were you having? Even though you have a shared instance, depending on how you were doing things, it is still possible to have some types of issues even though things are thread safe.

Comment: If you are caching the formatter per thread, you could just use one single DateFormatter and one single NumberFormatter and just mutate the properties on them to configure them each time you need to use them differently right? I wonder if that's more efficient or less?

Comment: Thanks for input. I think using NSThread dictionary is not required, as DateFormatter is thread safe, and thread local doesn't solve the mutation problem. Mutate dateFormat/ timeZone of DateFormat still can occur within same thread. NSThread dictionary only used for minimized such scope. The only solution is having DateFormatter designed as immutable class, but that's out of developer control. Viable way is to impose hard rule within the team, to not mutate DateFormatter once they are initialized.

Comment: @AnthonyMDev Don't ever mutate DateFormatter once it is initialized. It can cause difficult to trace bug especially your app is multi-thread. Create multiple DateFormatter instead. Having class/ struct designed as immutable, is a good way to reduce chance of having bug in app.

Answer (score 8):

Since Swift uses dispatch once methods for static properties creation it's really fast and safe to create `DateFormatter` in a such way.

```
extension DateFormatter {
    static let shortFormatDateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

Than just write

```
date = DateFormatter.shortFormatDateFormatter.string(from: json["date"])
```

Comment: Shared mutable state risks race conditions.

Comment: @ScottyBlades why is it mutable? You think DF has some kind of state inside? We can add another layer by separating them on different threads with NSThread's info dictionaries.

Comment: Throw this into a playground: `DateFormatter.shortFormatDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
print("your shortDate formatter is now medium length format: ", DateFormatter.shortFormatDateFormatter.dateFormat!)`, classes are passed by reference.  Unlike with structs which are passed by copy, the class instance is the same but the [values on that instance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1413514-dateformat) can change , creating shared mutable state, race conditions, and unexpected values, which are difficult to debug.

Comment: @ScottyBlades my point about safety is related to creation itself. We don't expect that client will change anything in that object. Obviously, not-knowing-client can create a race condition situation by using the same date formatter on different threads. Thats why I wrote about NSThread and its dictionary. If you need to remove possibility of that race condition physically then your only option is to create another abstraction level (by introducing new function or new class/struct). Increasing number of created date formatters affects performance - you're balancing between perf/safety/weight.

Comment: Author of the top answer did a great job pointing out cons and pros of this solution. There is no need in discussing these thing once again. :)

Comment: "We don't expect that client will change anything in that object" Lets say a developer wants to use this dateFormatter but only wants to change one part. The developer on my team that added this pattern in a project was the same user that assigned it to another var in order to change just one property. He's a brilliant developer. That goes to show how easy this practice is to create bugs. APIs should discourage, not facilitate bugs.

Comment: This is not related to race-condition or DateFormatter caching. This is just a typical misuse of reference type. If you want to be protected from this kind of mistakes you can hide cached formatters and leave proxy functions open to public.

Comment: It’s not a typical misuse of a reference type because this is a shared object.  Setting objects to private and exposing functions that don’t change the objects state is one way to make this safe.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion Caching `NSDateFormatter` is a good idea if your app is using that widely or through-out your app, it'll increase the performance of your app. If you need that in 1 or 2 places, it won't be a good idea. However changing the date format is not a good idea, it can lead you into undesired situations. (You need to keep track the current format each time before going to use it)

In one of my application I used a singleton with three date format objects(all three contains three different formats) as properties. And custom getters for each `NSDateFormatter`

```
+ (instancetype)defaultDateManager
{
    static DateManager *dateManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dateManager                = [[DateManager alloc] init];
    });

    return dateManager;
}

// Custom Getter for short date
- (NSDateFormatter *)shortDate
{
    if (!_shortDateFormatter)
    {
        _shortDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [_shortDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]
    }
    return _shortDateFormatter
}
```

Like this I implemented custom getters for the other two also.

Why I implemented custom getters ? Why I didn't allocate the `NSDateFormatter` during singleton initialization ?

It's because I don't want to allocate them in the beginning itself. I need to allocate it when it's needed for the first time (On a On Demand basis). In my app the all three `NSDateFormatters` are not widely used, that's why I chose such a pattern for implementing it. (My app is in Objective C, that's why I used the Objective C code here)

Comment: should I create a different formatter for each dateFormat? eg: one for "yyyy-MM-dd" one for "yyyy" and so on?

Comment: @SisterRay: IMO, yes you should.

Answer (score 2):

> Would either of those be a good or a horrible idea?

Introducing singletons (anytime you need a new variant of a formatter) is *not* a good solution. Creating formatters isn't *that* expensive.

Instead, devise ways to reuse and share instances of formatters and pass them around in your program, like regular variables. This approach is quite simple to introduce into an existing program.

Instruments will help you identify where your program creates many formatters, and you can consider how to reuse formatters based on that data.

> And is switching the format also expensive?

Don't bother mutating formatters you share, unless used in very specific/local contexts (such as a particular collection of views). This is going to be much easier to achieve expected results. Instead, *copy* then mutate if you need a variant of a shared formatter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a singleton, use dependency injection. Remember to follow the 0, 1, infinite rule.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule

Here, we clearly cant have 0, and while 1 sounds nice, if you are going to use it from multiple thread, then you can't have just one without it hanging. So, infinity.

A good way to approach this is just to be careful with how many you spawn, keep just one around for each thread you open up, and be sure that they get cleaned up as soon as you are done using them.

To help you, check out this other stackoverflow link - I am afraid my answer will be in line with theirs (keep the number of NSDateformatters down to a minimum). However, they may have some reasoning that was not covered in this thread (no pun inteded!)

[How to minimize the costs for allocating and initializing an NSDateFormatter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4442074/how-to-minimize-the-costs-for-allocating-and-initializing-an-nsdateformatter)

Also, if I may ask - if you are are faced with this question, perhaps there is somewhere in your program where a flow can be improved to avoid even needing so many formatters?

Answer (score 0):

In Objc:

Considering NSDateFormatter is considered thread-unsafe using a single formatter in your application may not be the best idea.  Having one formatter per thread may be a way to go.  Alternatively you could consider wrapping the formatter in a thread safe class.

From Apple Docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html

In Swift:

If swift offers thread safety of the class than there should be no problem having one instance.

Comment: I thought the 'let' made it thread safe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024549/dispatch-once-singleton-model-in-swift

Comment: @Tieme, if you can verify the instance is truly thread safe than it should be fine using one object for the app.

Comment: @Tieme the variable is created in a thread safe way, but the object itself is not thread safe. `let` in this case means that there will not be a race condition initializing the variable (like using `dispatch_once`). `let` does not promote an object which is ordinarily thread unsafe to one which is thread safe.

Comment: `DateFormatter` is not really thread-safe. I do not recommend trying to change dateFormat across different threads. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Example**

Based on @Mobile Ben answer: this is an example of a simple Swift singleton.

```
class YourDateFormatter {

    // MARK: - Properties

    static let sharedFormatter = YourDateFormatter()
    /// only date format
    private let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter
    /// only time format
    private let timeFormatter: NSDateFormatter

    // MARK: - private init

    private init() {

        // init the formatters

        dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

        // config the format

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle
        dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true

        timeFormatter.dateStyle = .NoStyle
        timeFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle

    }

    // MARK: - Public 

    func dateFormat(date: NSDate) -> String {
        return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    }

    func timeFormat(date: NSDate) -> String {
        return timeFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
    }

    func dateTimeFormat(date: NSDate) -> String {
        let dateFormat = self.dateFormat(date)
        let timeFormat = self.timeFormat(date)

        return dateFormat + " - " + timeFormat
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like to expand on **Mobile Ben**'s answer by providing an example:

```
import Foundation

public class DateFormatter : NSDateFormatter{

  public class func sharedFormatter() -> NSDateFormatter {
    // current thread's hash
    let threadHash = NSThread.currentThread().hash
    // check if a date formatter has already been created for this thread
    if let existingFormatter = NSThread.currentThread().threadDictionary[threadHash] as? NSDateFormatter{
      // a date formatter has already been created, return that
      return existingFormatter
    }else{
      // otherwise, create a new date formatter 
      let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
      // and store it in the threadDictionary (so that we can access it later on in the current thread)
      NSThread.currentThread().threadDictionary[threadHash] = dateFormatter
      return dateFormatter

    }

  }

}
```

*This is used in a library, that's why you can see the **public** modifier throughout.*

Comment: Sorry for getting to this late. I left my comments above.

Comment: You probably shouldn't name the class `DateFormatter`: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/ab63b511483de6d6152f8d75aa5838449dfb01e8/Foundation/NSDateFormatter.swift#L12

Comment: You should not reuse single `DateFormatter` for all `dateFormat`s in your application. That's what Apple engineers say on WWDC.