# NSDateFormatter on ios 5 - any other way to use?

Tags: ios5

I have a code that was working until iOS 4.3.5, now in iOS 5 it's not working:

```
//Example of date I'm using: Mon, 31 Oct 2011 15:57:55 BRST

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss vvvv"];
[formatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
NSString *dateString = [TBXML textForElement:[TBXML childElementNamed:@"pubDate" parentElement:XML]];
NSDate *data = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
[formatter release];
```

Now, data is coming (null). Does anybody know what I did wrong?

Regards!

EDIT:

I was looking in the file NSDateFormatter.h and I found:

```
// - (id)init; // designated initializer
```

init is commented, so I am not allowed to use [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] right? Is there any other way to create ah instance of NSDateFormatter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can init the NSDateFormatter with initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:

[NSDateFormat Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/initWithDateFormat:allowNaturalLanguage:)

SO-Question
[NSDateFormatter's init method is deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182314/nsdateformatters-init-method-is-deprecated/3182417#3182417)

Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Try this format:

```
@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss vvvv"
```

The docs are here.

http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score -1):

So what does `dateString` look like before you do anything to it?

That would help a lot.

Comment: //Example of date I'm using: Mon, 31 Oct 2011 15:57:55 BRST

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];...